# Is there a reason to use subtype as type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala

I was wondering whether there is a good reason to use subtype as functions type parameter?
Lets consider the following example:

```
scala> trait Animal { def sound: String }
defined trait Animal

scala> def f1[T <: Animal](a: T) = a.sound
f1: [T <: Animal](a: T)String

scala> def f2(a: Animal) = a.sound
f2: (a: Animal)String
```

Has *f1* some advantages over *f2*?

Comment: If `f1` needed to return a `T` or some type that referenced `T`, then sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there are no advantages in your example. Type parameters are usually used to connect different parts of the code, but information about `T` is effectively lost as it doesn't match anything. Consider another example:

```
def f1[T <: Animal](a: T) = (a.sound, a)

def f2(a: Animal) = (a.sound, a)
```

Now things are different as `T` is passed to a return type:

```
class Dog extends Animal { def sound = "bow-wow" }

f1(new Dog)
//> (String, Dog) = (bow-wow,Dog@141851fd)

f2(new Dog)
//> (String, Animal) = (bow-wow,Dog@5a1fe991)
```

In this case you can think of `f1` as of a template which is "instantiated" at compile time and effectively generates a specific method based on compile-time parameter types. So if you want to use `f1(new Dog)` where `(String, Dog)` is required it will compile, while `f2(new Dog)` won't.

Answer (score 2):

Both functions `f1` and `f2` are very similar. If you output the bytecode, you'll see up in the constants pool that they are denoted as:

```
#71 = Methodref          #12.#70       // Main$.f2:(LMain$Animal;)Ljava/lang/String;
#74 = Methodref          #12.#73       // Main$.f1:(LMain$Animal;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

As far as the bytecode is concerned, they are functions that take an `Animal` as a parameter and return `String`.

One situation where this gets more interesting is when you want to return a specific `T` (where `T <: Animal`). Keep in mind, the bytecode will still be the same, but at compile-time this gives more meaning and power to the `T` type parameter:

Imagine you have:

```
def f1[T <: Animal](a: T): T = a  // silly, I know
def f2(a: Animal): Animal = a
```

And you try this:

```
val s: Dog = f1(new Dog())
val t: Dog = f2(new Dog()) // NOPE
val u: Dog = f2(new Dog()).asInstanceOf[Dog] // awkward
```

That second line won't compile without casting, which sacrifices compile-time type-checking.

Comment: What is interesting is that your `f1` and `f2` will be compiled to the same code too.  Type parameters are erased.

Comment: Yes. After compilation, the bytecode would be the same. Type erasure would make it appear as though `f1` returns `Animal`. The point I'm trying to make there is the usefulness _at_ compile-time when the type parameters "matter".

Comment: I mentioned it because your started (I did it too originally) from "it compiles to the same bytecode".

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example where `f1` and `f2` have the same output type the `f2` function has an advantage before `f1` if you want to overload your method.

So for `f1` it will give an error:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Zoo {
  def f1[T <: Animal](a: T) = a.sound
  def f1[T <: Dog](a: T) = "Dog says " + a.sound
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:18: error: method f1 is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
         def f1[T <: Dog](a: T) = "Dog says " + a.sound
             ^
```

while with `f2` it works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Zoo {
  def f2(a: Animal) = a.sound
  def f2(a: Dog) = "Dog says " + a.sound
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala and JVM they have following function typing rule

> `S1 -> S2`  is subtype of `T1 -> T2`
>
> if and only if
>
> `S1` is subtype of `T1` and `T2` is subtype of `S2`

In your example,

```
   def f1[T <: Animal](a: T): String // T <: Animal -> String
   def f2(a: Animal): String // Animal -> String
```

By the function typing rule, `f1` is the subtype of `f2`

**In conclusion** `f1` and `f2` has no difference in real use cases

Please refer, the following link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types

Comment: Neither `f1` nor `f2` have types per se as they are not functions, they are methods. Also eta-expansion can give you different results depending on what you expect. Try `f1 _` in the REPL, you will be surprised.